# How to show that $(X-a)^+\le X^++|a|$

Tags: inequality

> How to show that $(X-a)^+\le X^++|a|$, where $X, a$ are real

Is the following OK;

$(X-a)^+ +(a-X)^+=|X-a|$

and If the claim (in the yellow box) is not true then also; $(a-X)^+> a^++|X|$

but $(X^++|a|)+(a^++|X|)\ge|X|+|a|\ge|X-a|$

(can we use here some symmetry argument ?)

Comment: $$|-a|=|a|$$  and $$|x+(-a)|\le|x|+|-a|$$

Comment: What does $X^+$ mean?

Comment: @Wojowu $X^+=X$, if $X>0$ or $0$ else

Comment: I see, thank you. I have never encountered this notation.

Answer (score 0):

If $X\le a$ then the inequality holds because the left side is non-positive and the right side is non-negative. If $X>a$ then $(X-a)^+=X-a\le X^+-a\le X^++|a|$ because $X\le X^+$ and $-a\le|a|$.